# Can't access detailViewController from UINavigationController

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, push

I'm trying to get a reference to my ***detailViewController*** in ***application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:*** method. But here I am faced with a problem.

I have next Views structure is *storyBoard* (for *iPad*):

*UISplitViewController* --> ***UINavigationController*** --> ***UITableViewController*** --> ***detailViewController***

I created segue with "**push**" style between *UITableViewControllerCell* and *detailViewController*

Screenshot: http://picturepush.com/public/13071076

I'm trying to get a reference to ***detailViewController*** in this way:

```
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [navigationController.viewControllers lastObject];
```

But in result I got reference to my ***UITableViewController***, instead of acceptable
***DetailViewController***. The *navigationController.viewControllers count* is 1 but there should be 2 (I think so).

I hope for your help.

Comment: When i works with same storyBoard structure for iPhone I can get reference with following code:                                      self.detailViewController = (ADDetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];                                              But why it does not work for iPad?

Comment: On which file do you call the code above?

Comment: I'm call it from TableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Since you created a segue with *push* style, the detailViewController will only be loaded after you tap on a table view cell. It will not be loaded on the app `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

I would suggest you try to make the detailViewController as a property in your table view controller.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *detailViewController;
```

Then in your app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, you can access the property:

```
UITableViewController *tableViewController = [navigationController.viewControllers lastObject];
DetailViewController *detailViewController = tableViewController.detailViewController;
```

But you will need to avoid using perform segue function and push the detail view controller whenever it is needed with the usual `pushViewController` method.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Yes, in my project I'm using detailViewController as property.